# google analytics api how to get content drill down using dimension and metrics

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am writing a program for myself in which i want to list the content drilldown of google analytics. what is the dimension and metrics to get that detail like shown in google analytics content drill down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely clear by what you mean with **content drilldown**.  But when I go into **Google Analytics -> Content -> Content Drilldown**, I get a table which lists in the first column all page path.  The dimension you would use here would be **ga:pagepath**.  And of course you could select any metric you desire (e.g. visits, pageviews, new visits, bounces, etc).

Now on Google Analytics I see you can further drill down on a particular pagepath and it will list out all variations with respect to query parameters that page was called with.  For example, if you had a pagepath vieworders.php, you might have the following listed:

```
/vieworders.php?orderid=100
/vieworders.php?orderid=101
etc....
```

But in the API it returns the pagepage with the associated parameters (i.e. it does not separate the pagepath from the queries).  You would have to write your own routine for this.

Comment: hhhmm.... as you had said... pagepath of dimension and pageviews of metrics worked... i added up all the values for each root folder path and it worked. and i will post that code after bug testing and completing it.

Comment: Yes. As you said with a little filtering (programming)